# Выделить в таблице sql красным цветом самый дорогой товар с использованием php

Tags: php, sql

Есть таблица pricelist, в ней столбец coast, нужно выбрать максимальное значение из этого столбца и выделить его в красный цвет в самой таблице с использованием php.

Полную таблицу вывожу вот так:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM pricelist";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));

if($result) {
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    echo ("<table>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>Наименование товара</th>
            <th>Стоимость, руб</th>
            <th>Стоимость опт, руб</th>
            <th>Наличие на складе 1, шт</th>
            <th>Наличие на складе 2, шт</th>
            <th>Страна производства</th>
            <th>Примечание</th>
        </tr>");
    for($i = 0; $i < $rows; ++$i) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        echo ("<tr>");
            for($j = 0; $j < 7; ++$j) {
                echo("<td>$row[$j]</td>");
            }
        echo("</tr>");
    }
  echo ("</table>"); 
}
```

подключение к таблице:

```
require_once 'db.php';

$link = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $username, $password, $dbname);

if(!$link) {
    die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Код надо прикладывать, а не картинки.

Comment: Igor R - Спасибо за ответ, исправлю как приеду домой. Может все же вы знаете как решить данный вопрос?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно с помощью MySQL узнать максимальную стоимость и потом сравнивать с ней. Можно перед выводом пробежаться по результатам запроса и сформировать новый массив с указанием максимального значения. Вот так примерно выглядет первый способ.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM pricelist";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));
$max_query = "SELECT MAX(coast) FROM pricelist";
$result_max = mysqli_query($link, $max_query) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));
$max_coast = mysqli_fetch_row($result_max)[0];

if($result) {
    echo ("<table>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>Наименование товара</th>
            <th>Стоимость, руб</th>
            <th>Стоимость опт, руб</th>
            <th>Наличие на складе 1, шт</th>
            <th>Наличие на складе 2, шт</th>
            <th>Страна производства</th>
            <th>Примечание</th>
        </tr>");

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
        if($row['coast'] == $max_coast)
        echo ("<tr style='background:red;'>");
        else
        echo ("<tr>");
            foreach($row as $key => $column) {
if($key == 'coast' && $column == $max_coast)
echo("<td style='color:yellow;'>$column</td>");
else
                echo("<td>$column</td>");
            }
        echo("</tr>");
        }


  echo ("</table>"); 
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, но всё равно не могу понять, как выделить именно максимальное значение? А так получается выделяется вся строка, где находится это максимальное значение

Comment: Сделал UPDATE, выделил значение жёлтым.

Comment: Спасибо, сработало!